# Missing choices 11 in case statement and failed synthesizing module

Tags: vhdl

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

entity mucodec is
    port (
        din     : IN std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        valid   : IN std_logic;
        clr     : IN std_logic;
        clk     : IN std_logic;
        dout    : INOUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        dvalid  : OUT std_logic;
        error   : OUT std_logic);
end mucodec;

architecture Behavioral of mucodec is
    type state_type is (St_RESET, St_ERROR, St_BOS_1, St_BOS_2, St_BOS_3, St_BOS_4, St_EOS_1, St_EOS_2, St_EOS_3, St_EOS_4, St_DECODE, St_Out);
    signal state, next_state : state_type := St_RESET;

    -- Define additional signal needed here as needed
begin
    sync_process: process (clk, clr)
    begin
        if clr = '1' then
            state <= St_RESET;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            state <= next_state;

        end if;
    end process;

    state_logic: process (state)
    begin
        -- Next State Logic
        -- Complete the following:
        next_state <= state;
        case(state) is
            when St_RESET =>
                if (valid = '1') THEN
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_ERROR =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "000") THEN
                    if (valid = '1' and din = "111") THEN
                        if (valid = '1' and din = "000") THEN
                            if ( valid = '1' and din = "111") THEN
                                next_state <= St_DECODE;
                            else
                                next_state <= St_ERROR;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if;
            when St_BOS_1 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "000") THEN
                    next_state <= St_BOS_2;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                else
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_BOS_2 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_BOS_3;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                else
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_BOS_3 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "000") THEN
                    next_state <= St_BOS_4;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                else
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_BOS_4 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_DECODE;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                else
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_EOS_1 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_EOS_2;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                else
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_EOS_2 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "000") THEN
                    next_state <= St_EOS_3;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                else
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_EOS_3 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_EOS_4;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                else
                    next_state <= St_BOS_1;
                end if;
            when St_EOS_4 =>
                if (valid = '1' and din = "000") THEN
                    next_state <= St_Out;
                elsif (valid = '1' and din > "111") THEN
                    next_state <= St_ERROR;
                end if;
            when St_DECODE =>
                if (valid = '1') THEN
                    for i in 0 to 7 loop
                        if (din = "001") THEN
                            if (din = "010") THEN
                                dout <= x"41";
                            elsif (din = "011") THEN
                                dout <= x"42";
                            elsif (din = "100") THEN
                                dout <= x"43";
                            elsif (din = "101") THEN
                                dout <= x"44";
                            elsif (din = "110") THEN
                                dout <= x"45";
                            end if;
                        elsif (din = "010") THEN
                            if (din = "001") THEN
                                dout <= x"46";
                            elsif (din = "011") THEN
                                dout <= x"47";
                            elsif (din = "100") THEN
                                dout <= x"48";
                            elsif (din = "101") THEN
                                dout <= x"49";
                            elsif (din = "110") THEN
                                dout <= x"4A";
                            end if;
                        elsif (din = "011") THEN
                            if (din = "001") THEN
                                dout <= x"4B";
                            elsif (din = "010") THEN
                                dout <= x"4C";
                            elsif (din = "100") THEN
                                dout <= x"4D";
                            elsif (din = "101") THEN
                                dout <= x"4E";
                            elsif (din = "110") THEN
                                dout <= x"4F";
                            end if;
                        elsif (din = "100") THEN
                            if (din = "001") THEN
                                dout <= x"50";
                            elsif (din = "010") THEN
                                dout <= x"51";
                            elsif (din = "011") THEN
                                dout <= x"52";
                            elsif (din = "101") THEN
                                dout <= x"53";
                            elsif (din = "110") THEN
                                dout <= x"54";
                            end if;
                        elsif (din = "101") THEN
                            if (din = "001") THEN
                                dout <= x"55";
                            elsif (din = "010") THEN
                                dout <= x"56";
                            elsif (din = "011") THEN
                                dout <= x"57";
                            elsif (din = "100") THEN
                                dout <= x"58";
                            elsif (din = "110") THEN
                                dout <= x"59";
                            end if;
                        elsif (din = "110") THEN
                            if (din = "001") THEN
                                dout <= x"5A";
                            elsif (din = "010") THEN
                                dout <= x"5B";
                            elsif (din = "011") THEN
                                dout <= x"5C";
                            elsif (din = "100") THEN
                                dout <= x"5D";
                            elsif (din = "101") THEN
                                dout <= x"5E";
                            end if;
                        end if;
                        dvalid <= '1';
                    end loop;
                next_state <= St_EOS_1;
                end if;
        end case;
    end process;

    output_logic: process (state)
    begin
        if (state = St_Out and valid = '1') THEN
            next_state <= St_RESET;
        end if;
    end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking your code. It is missing a choice for `St_Out` of the `state` signal. Case statement must cover all possible values. This can be done using the `when others =>` case, but this may not be suitable.

You will also have issues with this code. Your `state_logic` process is missing many signals. This will lead to simulation synthesis mismatch. You need to put every signal read inside the process inside the sensitivity list for an asynchronous process.

An easy fix for this is to use the VHDL 2008 `process(all)`. This will force the compiler to work what the sensitivity list should be from the code inside the process.